# MessageToDict: How to extract keys in multiple dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
from google.protobuf.json_format import MessageToDict

audio={'results': [{'alternatives': 
                      [{'transcript': 'His name is Charlie', 'confidence': 0.9259988}], 'resultEndTime': '7.700s', 'languageCode': 'en'}, 
                   {'alternatives': 
                      [{'transcript': 'and he lives in xxx street', 'confidence': 0.9259988}], 'resultEndTime': '11.900s', 'languageCode': 'en'}
                  ], 
                   'totalBilledTime': '14s', 
                   'requestId': '68687945678899765555'}
```

Hi! I want to extract 'transcript and' 'resultEndTime' from my dictionary. When I did

```
audio['results'][0]['alternatives'][0]['transcript']
```

it only prints "His name is Charlie", but what I want is "His name is Charlie and he lives in xxx street". Sometimes there are more than 2 dictionaries so I do not know how to merge them.

I also only want to extract the last 'resultEndTime' which is '11.900s'

Comment: "Sometimes there are more than 2 dictionaries so I do not know how to merge them." What is the rule that tells you, how to find the things to merge? Once you have all the pieces, what should be done with them to merge them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get each transcript and join it with a space between each one, and then get the last result's `resultEndTime`.

```py
transcript = " ".join(res['alternatives'][0]['transcript'] for res in audio['results'])
end_time = audio['results'][-1]['resultEndTime']
```

output from print:

```py
His name is Charlie and he lives in xxx street
11.900s
```